# If is not localhost statement htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, localhost

i'm currently forcing visitors to access all my websites (mostly Wordpress) over https, witch i do with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Now i was wondering if i can use an *if is not* statement, so if i work on my local environment, this won't work. For example:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'http://localhost:8888'">
    # live configuration 
</If>
<Else>
    # local configuration 
</Else>
```

What's the best way to do this?
Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://` is not part of match in `{HTTP_HOST}` variable .You need to use `!='localhost'`  If you are testing the on a local host  or `!='example.com'` If testing  this on `example.com` .

Full code

```
 <If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'localhost'">
# live configuration
</If>
<Else>
# local configuration 
</Else>
```