# Can I have conditional rows in a .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to have conditional parts in the .htaccess file (Apache Server)? I need different behaviour on my local development enviromnent (localhost) and the published environment.

For the moment I have different .htaccess files for my two environments. Localhost version looks like this:

```
#Rewrite everything to https
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I.e. at localhost I am **not** redirected to https (since it doesn't work locally). At my published site I have the following:

```
#Rewrite everything to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Instead of having two different .htaccess files I wonder if I can write a conditional part like this:

```
#Rewrite everything to https
If (NotOnLocalhost) Then
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
EndIf
```

Comment: I could see all your entries/Rules of .htaccess are commented(in your local shown samples of htaccess), not sure if this is a typo in question here? If they are actually commented starting by `#` they will NOT be considered in htaccess rules IMHO.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186811/if-is-not-localhost-statement-htaccess

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I was a little bit vague... I wan't to use the same .htaccess file both locally and published. Today I comment out the https section locally, and removes the comments when publishing. I wanted a method to make it more conditional... costaparas gave a good reference :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following.

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !localhost [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The rule will not apply to `Localhost` .